# Can $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ be integrated by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I was watching a video of a professor who said that $\int \frac{1}{1-x^2} dx$ can be done using the method of integration by parts. Though he skipped the solution and simply gave the answer, I tried solving it myself but I'm having difficulty moving forward. What I did was:

Let $u = \frac{1}{1-x^2}, du = \frac{2x}{(1-x^2)^2} dx , dv = dx, v=x$.

Then,
$$\int \frac{dx}{1-x^2} = \frac{x}{1-x^2} - \int \frac{2x^2}{(1-x^2)^2} dx$$

However, the new integral seems problematic. I tried doing the method again but the equation just ends up to be $0=0$.

Is integration by parts not a viable way of solving this integral?

P.S.: I already know the answer using a different method (partial fraction decomposition). I just want to know how to solve the integral in a different way.

Comment: Do you have a link to the video? Could it be just a slip of the tongue (“integration by parts” instead of “partial fractions”)?

Comment: @HansLundmark https://youtu.be/flwYlUfw4WU?t=306

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to suggest integration by parts in this case. You can notice that 
$$1=\frac{1}{2}(1+x)+\frac{1}{2}(1-x)$$
and split the fraction

Comment: He's a physicist, not a calculus teacher. He doesn't need to know the names of the calculus techniques he uses, he just needs to know how to get the answers. ("Integration by parts, partial fractions, whatever, it's got 'part' in it somewhere.") For his purposes it's even good enough to remember the answer even if he's completely forgotten how it is derived.

Comment: @DavidK  I would disagree with you. If someone says that by using the Newton's laws of gravitation(instead of motion), we get that force equals rate of change of momentum then what would the reaction of a physicist be albeit both have the name of Newton in common. Integration by parts is a technique to integrate and partial fraction is a technique to split into fractions with denominators which are powers of irreducibles and it's use is not limited to integration. Ofcourse the person who is teaching just had a slip of tounge and is experienced enough .

Comment: @DavidK Or for instance a worse scenario in which someone says Laplace transform and continues to use Fourier or Stieltjes Transoform and then says that it does not matter since it has "transform" in both names .

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Once again proving the old adage, "Sarcasm does not work on the Net." I don't think a physicist would mistake a Fourier transform for a Laplace transform. But I recall, for example, an occasion when students asked a physics professor what is the mathematical proof that their calculations with a Dirac delta "function" are correct, and the response was that that's something the mathematicians have worked out and those details are unimportant to the physicist.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Anyway, the point was, he's not in a business where one usually names the techniques for calculating an antiderivative. One just solves (or looks it up). I think it entirely plausible that on the spur of the moment he could not in fact recall the correct name of the partial fractions technique and so blurted out something that came to mind by association, when it would have been better not to try to name the specific technique at all but just say something like, "You learned how to do this in first-year calculus."

Comment: Using Mathematica to solve your generalised integration by parts problem gives $$\int \frac{1}{1-x^s} \, dx=\frac{x}{1-x^s}-B_{x^s}\left(\frac{1}{s}+1,-1\right)+C$$ - where $B_z(a,b)$ is the incomplete Beta Function.

Answer (score 2):

Partial fraction here is the best way, because
$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac{-1/2}{1-x}+\frac{1/2}{1+x}.$$
Then we have linear factor and it is not difficult to evaluate.

If you want a different method, you can consider write
$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{1-x^2})^2}$$
and then the trigonometric substitution $u(x)=\sin x$.

The way using integration by parts as you noticed seems really impractical, if you work with the second antiderivative you eventually you might be interested in $\int \frac{x^4}{(1-x^2)^3}\, dx$ and you don't get out of that growth of powers. At some point we might decide to stop you and use another method, but that wouldn't make much sense.

I guess they tried to say "partial fractions" in the video as the question suggested by the professor Hans in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to render $u=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$, matching the zero and pole of $u$ with poles of the integrand.

Then $x=\frac{u-1}{u+1}, dx=\frac{2du}{(u+1)^2}$

and so

$$\dfrac{dx}{1-x^2}=\dfrac{2\left(\dfrac{du}{(u+1)^2}\right)}{1-\left(\dfrac{(u-1)^2}{(u+1)^2}\right)}=\dfrac{2du}{(u+1)^2-(u-1)^2}=\dfrac{du}{2u}$$

from which the antiderivative may he read off via the definition of the natural logarithm as

$$\dfrac12\ln u+C=\dfrac12\ln\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)+C$$

Comment: Isn't that cheating? How did you invent such an elaborate substitution?

Comment: As I said, I choose a rational expression whose zeroes and poles  match singularities of the integrand.

Comment: I could also use $u=(1−x)/(1+x)$, putting the zero and pole in the opposite positions, and get similar results (the differential ends up as $−2du/u$).

Comment: @Dominique This is called an Euler Substitution. No wonder it is elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Here is to integrate by parts, albeit unnaturally
\begin{align}
I=\int \frac{dx}{1-x^2}
=\int\ln^{\frac12}\frac{1+x}{1-x}d\left(\ln^{\frac12}\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)
=\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}-I=\frac12 \ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For this integral, I prefer a hyperbolic substitution $x=\tanh t$

$$\int \frac{dx}{1-x^2}=\int\frac{\operatorname{sech}^2t}{1-\tanh^2t}dt=\int dt=t+C=\operatorname{artanh}x+C=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)+C$$
You can prove the logarithmic representation for $\operatorname{artanh}t$ with this:
$$y=\operatorname{artanh}t$$
$$t=\tanh y$$
$$t=\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{e^y+e^{-y}}=\frac{e^{2y}-1}{e^{2y}+1}$$
$$t(e^{2y}+1)=e^{2y}-1$$
Solve for $e^{2y}$, then solve for $y$

Answer (score 0):

**Trigonometric substitution also works**
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{d x}{1-x^2}& \stackrel{x=sin\theta}{=} \int \frac{\cos \theta d \theta}{\cos ^2 \theta} \\
& =\int \sec \theta d \theta \\
& =\ln |\sec \theta+\tan \theta|+C \\
& =\ln \left|\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right|+C \\
& =\ln \left|\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right| \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$